# Accessing power plans with WMI

Tags: python, wmi

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
for plan in c.Win32_PowerPlan():
    print plan
```

It returns `AttributeError: winmgmts:.Win32_PowerPlan` where it should return all the power plan instances on the machine. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: I tried googling for this `Win32_PowerPlan` method that you are invoking, but can't find it. What documentation are you following? You can list the available methods on an object using `dir(c)` and get some help with `help(c)`, btw.

Comment: It's [this class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd904531(v=vs.85).aspx), interrogated as explained [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html#querying) in the `wmi` tutorial.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I can't run this personally to help you out, but I'd try fishing through the available methods on your `wmi.WMI` instance (using `dir` and `help`). IPython can help you a lot with this with its auto-completion and `wmi.WMI?` style [help functions](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html). In this cookbok there is a mention of [power monitoring](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html#monitor-multiple-machines-for-power-events), if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `Win32_PowerPlan` class is not a direct `Win32` class in the `\root\CIMV2` namespace, which is why it's not in this list of [Win32 classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the documentation.

It actually resides in the `\\.\root\CIMV2\power` namespace as can be found by scrolling down to the table at the bottom of the `Win32_PowerPlan` [class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd904531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The code required to access this makes use of the `moniker` parameter of the `WMI()` class as follows:

```
c = wmi.WMI(moniker = "//./root/cimv2/power")
for plan in c.Win32_PowerPlan():
    print plan
```